# How do I use negation (and lists) in JIRA REST API?

Tags: jira-rest-api, jql

I need to recreate a JIRA search filter in JIRA REST API. 
I understand how to query for particular field values with "jql for REST", e.g.

```
curl -D- -u fred:fred -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://kelpie9:8081/rest/api/2/search?jql=assignee=fred&startAt=2&maxResults=2
```

But how do I represent this piece of query:

```
... AND (labels not in (label1, label2) OR labels is EMPTY) AND ...
```

Or maybe there is a way to reuse an existing filter instead of constructing the JQL query?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just realized that when I construct the JQL query in JIRA, I can see the modified "ulr-ready" version of the query in the browser address bar. Facepalm.